# Append matplotlib histogram plots to a list, without overwriting

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to write a function, such that it creates multiple histograms(using matplotlib.pyplot) using a for loop on some data. I append these plots to a list, and the list is returned.
But when I try to use show() on each of the plots, they are all the same plot, and all the plots are being overwritten.

I have tried using plt.clf() at the end of the for loop, but it does not work for me.

```
for data in data_list:
    n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x=data, bins='auto', color=color,
                                    alpha=0.7, rwidth=0.85)
    plt.xlabel('Values')
    plt.ylabel('Frequency')
    plt.grid(axis='y', alpha=0.55)
    plots.append(plt)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, maybe we should question the need: why do you want to keep all plots at hand? Why not save them after plotting `plt.savefig('xxxxx')`? Are you planning to animate all of the figures?

Second, if we want to keep all figures, `subplots` might be a handy tool. Note that you are still plotting **in one plot**, but calling `subplots` creates multiple axes and allow them to not interfere with each other. Try this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(0)
data_list = [np.random.randn(10) for _ in range(4)]
plots=[]
fig, axes = plt.subplots(4,1)
for i,data in enumerate(data_list):
    n, bins, patches = axes[i].hist(x=data, bins='auto', 
                                    alpha=0.7, rwidth=0.85)
    axes[i].set_xlabel('Values')
    axes[i].set_ylabel('Frequency')
    axes[i].grid(axis='y', alpha=0.55)
```

[For more info on `subplots`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html)

[For more info on multiple figures](https://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html#working-with-multiple-figures-and-axes)